# Xcode 6: storyboard size not changing when selecting w:Regular h:Regular from w:compact h:regular

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am working on a project in Swift, while I was using storyboards to create UI for both iPad and iPhone so I simultaneously need to change the size of my storyboard (I am using size classes). After I have designed the UI for my view for iPhone and iPad. I was connecting some outlets to both.

I finished connecting the outlets for iPhone when I changed the size from w:compact h:regular to w:Regular h:Regular, it does not change two views got changed but the one I was connecting outlets does not change.

I am using Xcode-6 beta-3. I think I cannot paste any image of Xcode as it is in beta mode.

Comment: can you please tell me how do you design your UI for ipad and iphone using size classes? I am using size classed for the first time and don't know much about it.

Comment: You can use "w any h any" configuration to get the UI for both and then change to "w compact h regular" for iPhone and "w regular h regular" for ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked again automatically. after some time my Xcode crashed and the next time i choosed that i worked for me